# QField showing position is outside raster image?

Tags: qfield

I am a QGIS beginner and I have been asked to map an area that is being reforested. The project itself is quite easy, I have to generate a shapefile containing the polygons that delimit areas with different tree species, using aerial images as backgound. The map should be displayed in QField, to facilitate the operation in the field. They did not give me any georeferenced aerial images, so I made a collage with screenshots from satellite immages using Photoshop, and I georeferenced the raster (WGS 84) with the georeferencer plugin of QGis, using coordinates that I got from Google Earth. Before making the shapefile I wanted to try the project in QField to make sure that the localization was working well but my position is outside the raster image, where it should be.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to overlay your raster with another basemap (openstreetmap, ...) to be sure it's correctly georeferenced?

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you for your answer. How can I verify that the raster is correctly georeferenced with Openstreetmap? Thanks

Comment: If you load both layers and they visually "match".